# Problem with JSon

Tags: javascript, json

I'm not getting concatenate the variables to make an acceptable result for json, can someone give me an idea of ​​the correct form of concatenation?

I'm doing this:

```
date: '{"sUserName": "' + nomeUser'","' + + '" sPassword ":"' + password +'"}',
```

and the result is as follows:

```
{"sUserName": "a", "" sPassword ":" a "}
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
'{"sUserName": "' + nomeUser'","' + + '" sPassword ":"' + password +'"}'
```

with

```
'{"sUserName": "' + nomeUser + '","' + 'sPassword":"' + password +'"}'
```

You have an extra '+' and an extra ". And here's a simple way to avoid this in the future:

```
var obj = {}; obj.sPassword = 'test'; obj.sUserName = 'p'; JSON.stringify(obj)
```

Comment: i used this but happening other error: "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'sUserName'."